# std::function concurrency with assignment operator and call operator

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, std-function

Can `std::function::operator=` and `std::function::operator()` be called concurrently?

Is it undefined behavior to do a `std::function::operator=` on **thread one** while doing a `std::function::operator()` on **thread two**.

I assume this might be an atomic operation and we can't be halfway between which function gets invoked. I'm not concern about which one runs only that we are not in some invalid state.

Comment: If you rephrase the question, my hope is the answer becomes obvious. Something like "Can I execute a function while assigning a new function at the same time?" Or maybe "Can I run program x at the same time I'm replacing it with program y?"

Comment: "**[res.on.objects]/1** The behavior of a program is undefined if calls to standard library functions from different threads may introduce a data race. The conditions under which this may occur are specified in 20.5.5.9. [ Note: Modifying an object of a standard library type that is shared between threads risks undefined behavior unless objects of that type are explicitly specified as being sharable without data races or the user supplies a locking mechanism. —end note ]"

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Could I get this as an answer.

Comment: If the `std::function` contains a lambda, then reassigning the `std::function` will free the old lambda while it is still executing. And even if it doesn't contain a lambda, assigning it while `operator()` is trying to decide what to do will result in confusion (calling the newly-assigned member function on the old object, or calling a partly-assigned function pointer).

Comment: @RaymondChen That fact is very interesting. Would it be true if I used a bind?

Comment: It is true no matter what you do, because it is explicitly called out as the standard as an illegal operation, as Igor Tandetnik noted. I was just giving some examples of what could go wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> "[res.on.objects]/1 The behavior of a program is undefined if calls to
>   standard library functions from different threads may introduce a data
>   race. The conditions under which this may occur are specified in
>   20.5.5.9. [ Note: Modifying an object of a standard library type that is shared between threads risks undefined behavior unless objects of
>   that type are explicitly specified as being sharable without data
>   races or the user supplies a locking mechanism. —end note ]" –

Comment by: Igor Tandetnik

That being said I found a workaround to do what I wanted. It's possible to do an assignment in the call operator. This means I don't need to do the assignment on a different thread.